# Managed Metadata Fields not showing up in preview mode

Tags: managed-metadata, publishing-site, publishing-page

In our SharePoint 2013 Publishing page, managed metadata fields doesn't show in preview, they show up only in edit mode or after we publish page.

Is this bug?

Thanks in advance.